# Linq query to filter out item's that are not equal to text that the users types

Tags: c#, linq, uitableview

I'm trying to filter my tableView items with a Linq query.
I have a string array that contains all the names from a database.
And when the user types in a search keyword I want to filter my tableView so it only display's the names that matches the words that the user typed in.

For a short example I just added a array with static data.

I got the following method with the Linq query in it:

```
void filterTableView(string searchtext) {
    Console.WriteLine("filterTableView");

    string[] oldItems = {
        "Bas", "Mitch", "Rob", "Mark"
    };
    var newItems = oldItems.Where(oldItems.Contains(searchtext)).ToArray();
}
```

So how can I achieve this, I can't figure it out and got stuck with it for 3 hours.

Comment: Except your code has syntax error, I dont get whats wrong here. Try change this part: Where(x=>x.Contains(searchtext))

Comment: @Szer You're right there was an error in my query, I've tried several queries that didn't have syntax errors but I could't achieve what I wanted.

Comment: @Bas, Does query provided by Szer work for you?

Comment: @MaciejLos I don't know it returns: 'System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateWhereIterator>c__Iterator1F`1[System.String]' i've tried to convert it .ToString(). But I'm not sure how I can convert this to a string since im completely new to Linq

Comment: @Bas, Please, provide exact query you're using now.

Comment: @MaciejLos the query i'm currently using: var newItems = oldItems.Where(x => x.Contains(searchtext))

Comment: @Bas, Query is perfect, but i think that you're trying to bind data returned by the linq query. Note that your method is type of: void, so it shouldn't return anything. If i'm wrong, an issue is somewhere else.

Comment: @MaciejLos The only thing that I want to to with the data from the line query is sending it to a class which fills my tableview data. Right now when I just print it out I get this: System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateWhereIterator>c__Iterator1F`1[System.String]. I've tried .ToString(); But that doesn't work.

Comment: Here is a working sample: http://rextester.com/OCEQP19624

Comment: @DhwanilShah thank you so much. After being stuck in this for hours I couldn't get my mind to think normal. When I see your solution now it's quite easy. Thanks!:)